# How to recreate bson query with `elemMatch`

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

For reference, example object schema

```json
{
  "some": "",
  "field": "",
  "imageIds": [
    <objectIds>
  ]
}
```

Hopefully an easy one, I am trying to recreate the following bson query using Java:

`{ "imageIds": {$elemMatch: {$eq:ObjectId('6335f3c338a79a4377aea064')}} }`

When querying in MongoDb compass, this works as intended (Returning objects with given ObjectId in the `imageIds` array)

What I think this should look like is:

`elemMatch("imageIds", eq(new ObjectId("6335f3c338a79a4377aea064")))`

But this returns nothing. Debugging and using `toBsonDocument().toString()`, it looks like drastically different bson than I was expecting:

`{"imageIds": {"$elemMatch": {"_id": {"$oid": "6335f3c338a79a4377aea064"}}}}`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Actually you can query the element in array with `{ imageIds: ObjectId("6335f3c338a79a4377aea064") }` without `$elemMatch` operator.

Comment: Huh, unintuitive, but seems to work. If you make an answer I will mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you perform the query for the document with the array field containing a specific element without the `$elemMatch` operator.

```
{ imageIds: ObjectId("6335f3c338a79a4377aea064") }
```

Reference: [Query an Array for an Element](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element)